# Hide Subsection In tabel of content

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning

I want the two subsections with low opacity i want that just the section title visible
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you want to **hide** the subsection or just make it more difficult to see (like the other sections that you show in the image)?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Please post the code you are using in the form of a minimal document, cf. [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: yes i want it more difficult to see like others

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the appearance of the toc with `\tableofcontents[currentsection,subsectionstyle=shaded/shaded/shaded]`

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\begin{document}

\section{section name}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{section name}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents[currentsection,subsectionstyle=shaded/shaded/shaded]
\end{frame}

\subsection{section name}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\subsection{section name}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{section name}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify the use of `shaded/shaded/shaded`?  Which entry does what?  What other values are allowed?